# Search engines and in-line templates

Tags: javascript, html, seo, handlebars.js

First, I'm not a SEO expert, I'm a programmer and for me this topic is obscure :-).

What does search engine do when it encounters `<script type= text/template>`?

I've seen similar question about text/template type for script tag.

We now that the browser ignores it, but what search engine bot do with this script type? It ignores it or the risk is to be indexed with the keywords inside the text/template script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search engines ignore script tags, period.